# How to make menu fixed, in fluid website?

Tags: css

http://www.eco1furniture.ca/

When resizing the page down the main-menu goes to a 2nd line. I know this is supposed to happen with the site being fluid. But is there a way of keeping it fixed (on one line)?

[image: main-menu]

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: So you'd like the menu to have a minimum width and if the window is smaller than that, the user should have to scroll?

Comment: I'd like the full menu to stay on one line, regardless of screen resolution.

Comment: You have two choices if you want to keep everything on one line: either you can make everything smaller, including font size etc, so that it will fit within the screen width; or you can specify a `min-width` on the menu bar so that it is always wide enough to fit all the items on one line (users with narrow screens will have to scroll horizontally).  I guess a third option is to remove or hide the items that don't fit.  What would you like to do?

Comment: Well a drop down box appears when it gets too narrow. So I guess min width is the answer. It seems to act funny though when I set it. I set it too 850px, and the main-menu wrapper border then sticks outside of the main wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a few changes to ensure the menu doesn't wrap onto two lines under "normal" conditions, but I don't think you can ever be certain it won't happen. For instance, the menu width will depend on the browser zoom level, font and font-size.

Using my browser defaults, your menu is 865px wide. Taking the gutters into consideration, the max-width of the small-screen stylesheet should be 972px, so the drop down menu appears before the menu goes onto two lines. 975px would be a reasonable value to account for some of the idiosyncrasies of different browsers, but it still assumes the user is at 100% zoom, and using the font and font-size you've specified.

responsive.css - line 51

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 975px) {
```

Setting a min-width on the menu itself suffers the same problems and as you discovered causes the menu to extend out of the main wrapper.

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything, menu still goes to a 2nd line. @media only screen and (max-width: 975px) {
 
 .wrapper {
  width: 89%;
 }
 
 #main-menu {
  width: 70%;
 }

Max width was set at 1100px previously.

Comment: Should either of those %'s be changed also?

Comment: I believe you changed the wrong line. It's line 51, not line 17. The next line is `#main-menu { width: 65%; }` not `.wrapper { width: 89%; }`

Comment: You were correct on the wrong line number..oops..lol But the result is the same :( I do appreciate you helping Enrico!

Comment: Resize your window until it's _just_ big enough that the menu doesn't wrap and paste this - `javascript:alert(window.innerWidth);` - into the address bar and hit enter to get the right `max-width` for line 51. However, this is probably a perfect example of the differences between settings, browsers, and OSes. _Your_ menu is probably wider than mine, so 975px is too small. You can gradually increase that value until you can't resize your window without the menu wrapping, but then it will just be the right size for _your_ configuration.

Comment: IE told me 995, FF that script did nothing. Either way. When resizing the window, the 2nd line is created at around 870px, when setting the max-width on line 51 to 995px. I'm confused.

Comment: How do you figure the 2nd line is created at around 870px? Changing `max-width` on line 51 to 995px should mean the drop down replaces the menu when the window is less than 995px. I'm also confused. Does the drop down appear at all when you resize?

Comment: I put a pixel ruler on the screen, and when it hits about 870, the menu wraps to the 2nd line. The drop-down appears at 775px, Which I would assume is line 96 - @media only screen and (max-width: 767px)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20289/discussion-between-enrico-and-ken)